# Run ruby script from OS X Application

Tags: ruby, macos, cocoa

I'd like to write an OS X application that can execute some code that is really simple to write in ruby and that I prefer not to port in swift. 
Is it possible to include somehow ruby scripts into an OS X app and then call and get data from this script exchanging info with my swift code? For example I can write the function "return_random" in Ruby and call it from swift getting the result that comes from that function?

I know... it sounds really complex but it would be extremely useful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSUserUnixTask(url: NSURL) to execute a script. You can feed standard input and read standard output by creating NSPipe() for each and attaching them to the task.

If your App is sandboxed, you can only execute from the ApplicationScriptsDirectory. If you aren't sandboxed you should be able to execute anywhere.

Here is a brief example:

```
let script = try NSUserUnixTask(URL: url)
let inpipe = NSPipe()
let outpipe = NSPipe()
script.standardInput = inpipe.fileHandleForReading
script.standardOutput = outpipe.fileHandleForWriting
script.executeWithArguments(nil, completionHandler: nil)
inpipe.fileHandleForWriting.writeData(inputData)
script.standardInput?.closeFile()
inpipe.fileHandleForWriting.closeFile()
let out = outpipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
script.standardOutput?.closeFile()
outpipe.fileHandleForReading.closeFile()
return String(data: out, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.rubymotion.com, it seems that is what you need:

> RubyMotion lets you quickly develop cross-platform native apps for
>   iOS, Android and OS X, all using your favorite editor and the awesome
>   Ruby language you know and love.